# how to add new php object to an array of objects

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, object

i have a user class with a function to add a user.

i also have a form that triggers an ajax call on submit which passes a query string for the username and potentially other information to the controller.

everytime the controller gets called via ajax, it creates a new instance of my user class and calls the add user function by passing the query strings as parameters.

is there a way where i can output an array of usernames that have been submitted without storing it in a sessions.

Comment: Store it in the database or filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

I use a global variable to indicate I'm currently in AjAX mode. So when you call the AJAX controller set a global variable.

Then just skip the add user function by checking to see if the global variable is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are to store it:

1. In a session.
2. In a file.
3. In a database.

PHP is not a persistent service, and will not remember anything between requests other than what has been stored either in a session, or in an external store.